# Make a Gtk.Scale have the same value as a Gtk.Spin

Tags: gtk, vala, genie

My objective is to make the slider in the scale be in sync with the value in the spin and vice-versa. I've tried some alternatives, but I am not finding a way of getting the value where the scale is so that I can set the new spin position.

The little exercise has a small check button that should sync both widgets. I am trying to do this sync through the toggled function, but I am stuck now.

Here is the code so far:

```
uses
    Gtk

class TestWindow:Window
    _spin:Gtk.SpinButton
    _scale:Gtk.Scale
    construct ()

        //General aspects of the window
        title = "Spin and scale"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( Gtk.main_quit )

        //create the spin button
        spinAdjustment:Gtk.Adjustment = new Gtk.Adjustment(50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0)
        scaleAdjustment:Gtk.Adjustment = new Gtk.Adjustment(50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0)
        _spin:SpinButton = new Gtk.SpinButton(spinAdjustment, 1.0,1)

        //create the horizontal scale
        _scale:Scale = new Gtk.Scale(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, scaleAdjustment);

        //create the check button
        var check =  new Gtk.CheckButton.with_label ("Sync both scales!")
        check.toggled.connect(toggled)

        // organize it in a box
        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start(_spin, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start(_scale, true, true, 0)
        box.pack_start(check, true, true, 0)
        add( box )

    def toggled ()
        message(_spin.get_value().to_string())
        //if _scale.get_value_pos() !=  _spin.get_value()
        //  _scale.set_value_pos(_spin.get_value())



init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Can anyone give me a little pointer on how to solve this?

Comment: You could try binding `_spin.value` to `_scale.adjustment.value`. I forget how to do this with Vala. I also don't know what happens if `_scale.adjustment` changes...

Comment: That's how I would do it, too.  The method is `GLib.Object.bind_property`.  As for what happens if _scale.adjustment changes, you can create a bidirectional binding if you want (use the `GLib.BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL` flag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working example based on your code:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gtk

class TestWindow:Window

    _spin:SpinButton
    _scale:Scale

    construct ()
        //General aspects of the window
        title = "Spin and scale"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( main_quit )

        //create the spin button
        spinAdjustment:Adjustment = new Adjustment( 50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0 )
        scaleAdjustment:Adjustment = new Adjustment( 50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0 )
        _spin = new SpinButton( spinAdjustment, 1.0, 1 )

        //create the horizontal scale
        _scale = new Scale( Orientation.HORIZONTAL, scaleAdjustment );

        //create the check button
        var check =  new CheckButton.with_label ( "Sync both scales!" )
        check.toggled.connect( toggled )

        // organize it in a box
        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _spin, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _scale, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( check, true, true, 0 )
        add( box )

    def toggled ()
        message(_spin.get_value().to_string())
        if _scale.get_value() !=  _spin.get_value()
            _scale.set_value(_spin.get_value())

init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Your example is nice and obviously when you run it you will understand how the user interaction can be improved.

For the Genie code itself there are a couple of points:

- When you state a variable identifier and its type this is a new declaration of the variable. Often the Vala compiler will warn you, but it doesn't when a variable with the same name is declared in a class's method as well as the scope of the whole class. So `_spin:SpinButton = new Gtk.SpinButton(spinAdjustment, 1.0,1)` should just be `_spin = new Gtk.SpinButton(spinAdjustment, 1.0,1)` because you have already declared `_spin`. The same applies to `_scale`.
- You have used the `get_value_pos` method of `Gtk.Scale` and this causes a type mismatch error: `Equality operation: 'double' and 'Gtk.PositionType' are incompatible`. The Vala documentation for [Gtk.Scale](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Scale) says "To use it, you’ll probably want to investigate the methods on its base class, Range, in addition to the methods for GtkScale itself." Under `Gtk.Range` there is a [get_value](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Range.get_value) method that returns a `double`, the same type you need to match the `get_value` from the `SpinButton`. This is the concept of inheritance, which is already being used for the `Window`

Comment: Thomas, it seems that bind_property would be a great approach for syncing both widgets, the problem is that Gtk.Scale has no "value" property that I can bind to the Gtk.Spin value.  I am trying ```_spin.bind_property("value", _scale, "adjustment.value", BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL )```, however I am getting ```GtkScale has no property called 'adjustment.value'```. Changing adjustment.value to value generates the same error at execution. Do you have any suggestions on this? Or should I move on to another strategy? Thanks.

Comment: Try:
`_spin.adjustment.bind_property( "value", _scale.adjustment, "value", BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL )`

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. That made the error go away, but the result is that the app actually stalls when I try to manually change the spin value... I will try to think of other approach...

Comment: The example line in my comment worked fine with the code given in my answer above. Just copy and paste the line to the end of the `construct` block. You are now, however, asking another question.